# Is checking /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf sufficient to know that no server is trying to falsely represent itself as another?

Tags: linux, security, dns, route, hosts

Say I want to make sure that no malicious actor or process has made an attempt to falsely represent a legitimate web server with their own malicious server on Linux, anticipating that the user will access an external executable file.

For example, adding an entry like `12.34.56.78 legitsite.com`, then the next time I visit `legitsite.com/downloads/setup.sh`, I actually download `12.34.56.78/downloads/setup.sh`, which is malware.

It looks like at the very least I'd have to check `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`, but is there anything else I would want to check too? Should I check the `ip route` command for entries appearing to target `legitsite.com` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing you can do if some other party has the root privileges to modify name resolution. That means they can already mess with all your software. You've lost. Nothing you can do on your machine could be suppressed by that almighty attacker.

But: the appropriate response to the possibility that someone was able to do that is very simple, and already deployed: It's TLS with certificate checking.

That's it. That's all there is to it. Use `https`. Nothing less will do, if you can't trust the network, than proper cryptography, and TLS is that.

Setting up your webserver to support that is trivial these days; use letsencrypt.org, and as soon as it works, enable strict host security.

Comment: Seconded, https is half the solution.  But https only tells you that the connection is private.  You could still be talking to the devil.

Comment: @markgraf nope! TLS has certificate authorities for exactly that reason. Hence the recommendation to use letsencrypt.com.

Comment: Certificate authorities have proven time and again that they are not trustworthy.
Remember the CAs that gave google-certs to anyone paying without verification?
It's a bandaid at best as long as you need to trust third parties somewhere in the US --which are legally obliged to fake certificates for US police et al.
It's convenient, it's better than http.  But that's it.  A self-signed cert offers the exact same security.

Comment: You would have to go the extra mile with certificate pinning on the server side, and very close inspection of the certificate on the  client side.  Both of which is way beyond what people usually do.  And noone ever bothers to ask the certs fingerprint over the phone.

Comment: With respect to the first part, my answer is that it's possible that a vulnerability on some program or library on the user's system could allow write access to a specific sensitive resource like `/etc/hosts` but not complete root access.

Comment: @GovindParmar that sounds extremely unlikely. But compromised DNS configurations do exist, so, yes. Use https – markgraf is right, it's not a perfect protection, but it is definitely a big step ahead. You can configure your browser to always try to use HTTPS (there's a plugin called "https everywhere").

Comment: @markgraf there's a lot of bold claims in those comments which I'm not inclined to believe your interpretation without authoritative sources. But the solution isn't pinning certificates. If you don't trust a CA remove trust form then from your system. If you want to be sure, create your own CA certificate, trust that on your system and be your own CA.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the attribute of the file became immutable using chattr linux command.

This some sample of using chattr command.

```
[root@my-server ~]# lsattr /etc/hosts
-------------e- /etc/hosts
[root@my-server ~]# chattr +i /etc/hosts
[root@my-server ~]# lsattr /etc/hosts
----i--------e- /etc/hosts
[root@my-server ~]# chattr -i /etc/hosts
[root@my-server ~]# lsattr /etc/hosts
-------------e- /etc/hosts
```

so the other user can not modified the file.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Checking your own /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf will give you no information at all.  These are files on your host, and they have no effect against a foreign, external host that is not under your control.

An attacker may send you fake IP-adresses, or try and trick you in other ways.